# find the value of volume$(Q)$ in term of measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory

Rudin Theorem $2.19$.

> For  $n=1,2,3...$ we let $ P_n$ be the set of all $x \in R^k$ whose corrdinates are integral multiples  of $2^{-n}$ and let $\Omega_n$ be the collection of all $2^{-n}$ boxes with  corner at points of $P_n$ . If $a\in R^k$ and $\delta >0 $, we shall call the set
> $Q(a,\delta) = \{x \in \Bbb{R}^k \mid a_i \le x_i < a_i + \delta \}$

> If $Q \in \Omega_r$, then $\mbox{vol}(Q) = 2^{-rk}$; and if $n > r$, the set $P_n$ has exactly $2^{(n-r)k}$ points in $Q$

My  doubt :  why  $\mbox{vol}(Q) = 2^{-rk}?$

My attempt :

$$Vol(Q)= \prod_{r=1}^{k}(\frac{z_r}{2^r}-\frac{1}{2^r})=(\frac{z_1}{2^1}-\frac{1}{2^1})\times(\frac{z_2}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^2})\times.......\times(\frac{z_k}{2^k}-\frac{1}{2^k})=\frac{1}{2}(z_1-1)\times\frac{1}{2^2}(z_2-1)\times..\times\frac{1}{2^k}(z_k-1)$$

$$Vol(Q)= \prod_{r=1}^{k}(\frac{z_r}{2^r}-\frac{1}{2^r})=\frac{1}{2^{1+2+3....+k}}(z_1-1)(z_2-1)..(z_k-1)$$

$$Vol(Q)=\frac{1}{2^{k(k-1)/2}}(z_1-1)(z_2-1)..(z_k-1)\neq 2^{-rk}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each box in $\Omega_r$ has side length $2^{-r}$ and is $k$-dimensional. So the volume is $(2^{-r})^k = 2^{-rk}$.

Comment: I'm not getting   why $\Omega_r$ has side length $2^{-r}?$

Comment: This is by definition: "let $\Omega_n$ be the collection of all $2^{-n}$ boxes...". This means each box in $\Omega_n$ has side length $2^{-n}$.